# Co-occurence matrix in Python given just two columns

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Apologies for the simple question, but the references on this online all seem to relate to NLP and I think my scenario is rather simple.

I have a similar dataframe of categories:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,62,3,3], 'y':[5,6,6,1,1]})
```

I would like to create a square matrix, that has all unique values in x and u as columns/rows. In this case, it would be [1,2,3,5,6,62] and the values in the matrix is how often each pair of categories appears. So the Row '1' and Column '5' would have value = 1, and Row '3', Col '1' would = 2.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df["x"], df["y"])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot_table(index='x', columns='y', aggfunc='size').fillna(0)
```

You can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for that where the aggregation function is the count of each combination (`size`) and the rows (index) is `x` and the column is `y` (of course you can also do it vice versa).

I added `fillna(0)` for combinations that do not exist so it would look nicer.

Comment: This doesnt give a square matrix though, I would like that all unique values in X and Y are on both the row and column axes, and that the square matrix will end up being symmetrical. That is, Row 3 and Col 1 = 2, and Row 1 and Col 3 = 2.